# SQL Distinct value within distinct value from another table

Tags: sql-server

How would I go about creating a SQL query to get the result of a Distinct value within the distinct top 6 value from another table? What I have is trade show sessions, and 3 tables; sessions, tracks, and sessiontracks (a composite table).  I can get the top 6 distinct records of the sessions, but I have repeating tracks within the sessions.  I need the tracks to only be displayed once.  Here is the basic query to get a random distinct 6 records (sessions):

```
select distinct top 6(s.sessionid) sessionid
    ,s.title
    ,s.starttime
    ,t.showid
    ,trackid
    ,t.track
    ,st.sessiontracksid
    ,NEWID() as randomCheck
from session s
    ,tracks t
    ,sessiontracks st
where st.sessionid = s.sessionid 
    and st.tracksid = t.trackid 
    and s.showid = 43
order by NEWID()
    ,s.sessionid
    ,s.starttime desc
```

Comment: You should get with the `JOIN` syntax, now that its after 1992.

Comment: Show us some sample data, output of your query, etc.

Comment: why you adding "NEWID() as randomCheck" is same select. you should be doing it in outer select. also s.starttime could be also contributing to getting duplicate Tracks.

Comment: EkoostikMartin -- was that suppose to be funny (okay, ha, ha).  I posted this for help not "slams." If you have suggestions to help, then please do.  Thanks.

Comment: sessionid title starttime showid trackid track sessiontracksid randomCheck
1817 ADA Updates for Hospitality: Pool Lifts and More 2013-09-18 10:00:00 43 184 Hospitality 2159 0444CDFD-B243-4DF9-9B6C-004522C380EF

Comment: @user2957231 Please update your question with some create table statements for your tables to make it easier on us to re-write your query. This doesn't sound hard, but most of us are pretty lazy so having a schema to work with would let us pound out your query in a minute or two.

Comment: Try removing the `distinct` and use `group by` for all your unique fields and `max` for those that are repeating e.g. `max(t.track)`